# Почему блоки не отображаются на странице?

Tags: python, django, шаблонизаторы

В общем столкнулся с такой проблемой блоки не отображатся на странице, что делать особо не знаю так как с шаблонизатором работаю впервые.
это код от views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def sale(request):
    return render(request, 'sale.html')
```

это код от блока

```html
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block sale %}

<td class ="sale">
      <img src="картинка">

        <h1 class="description">ОписаниеОписаниеОписаниеОписание</h1>

  <a class="buy" href="#openModal" >
    <span >Купить</span></a>
  <h1 class="price">цена</h1>
  </td>


{% endblock %}
```

это код страницы на который должжен выводится блок

```
{% block sale %} {% endblock %}
```

это код urls.py(приложения)

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
app_name = 'Homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('Home', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('sale', views.sale, name='sale'),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='media/images/logo1.png', permanent=True)),
]
```

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он должен выводиться? Документацию по шаблонизаторам читали? Что в файле `index.html`?

Comment: `{% block sale %} {% endblock %}` или вам нужны ещё теги `link` ?

Comment: @andreymal было бы неплохо скинуть, я бы с радостю прочитал

Comment: Я сейчас глянул в urls.py и меня сильно смущает, что на один и тот же путь `''` вы повесили целых три разных вьюхи — Django не сможет понять, какую из них в каком случае запускать, и запустит какую попало

Comment: @andreymal Вот это я исправил также функцию sale я вынес из класса IndexView, так-же можете кинуть документацию по шаблонизаторам